# How to mock $(element).show and ko.mapping.fromJS in jasmine test case?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, jasmine

Here is my code:

```
TestViewModel.prototype.edit = function(pId, pData) {
    self.modalId = '#header';
    $(self.modalId).modal('show'); //error
    self.id(ko.mapping.fromJS(pData).id()); //how to mock this ?
}
```

This is the Jasmine test case:

```
  it("calling edit method", function() {
        var modalId = $("#cc-accessControlUserModal");
        var EditData = {id:"i10060"};
        spyOn($.fn, 'modal');
        self.TestViewModel.edit("i10060",EditData);
  });
```

However, this will give me:

> error: modal() method does not exist

So, question is: how to mock `$(element).show` and `ko.mapping.fromJS` in a Jasmine test case?

Comment: Your question is interesting on its own, but as a related aside: I'd suggest moving any dependency on a View-related plugin like `modal` to a `bindingHandler`.

Comment: To comment on your actual question though: are you loading up your lib with the `modal` fn? If I try to convert your code into a repro everything works: see [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4hv7Lyth/) (specifically its External Resources).

Answer (score 0):

This is an older question but I recently ran into the same issue. If you are using karma to run your jasmine scripts, Add the bootstrap library to the karma.config file, under files.

```
files: [
      'node_modules/es6-shim/es6-shim.js',
      'node_modules/reflect-metadata/Reflect.js',
       ...
      'node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js',
      'node_modules/jquery-mask-plugin/dist/jquery.mask.js',
      'node_modules/jquery-ui/ui/core.js',
      'node_modules/jquery-ui/ui/datepicker.js',

      //Append dependencies to this list
      'node_modules/bootstrap/js/modal.js',
...
]
```

In my case, since i did not need the entire bootstrap library, i only included the modal file.

This is the karma config documentation: [karma doc](http://karma-runner.github.io/1.0/intro/configuration.html)